# How does the 2nd for loop is working like it is inside the 1st for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop

I tried to solve a Codility sample test with nested for loop but it did not perform well enough. Then I tried the following solution and I work fine. But I don't have an idea about how does the 2nd for loop is working in the 2nd solution.

The first solution does not have enough performance. https://app.codility.com/demo/results/training5Z4ZB8-385/

The second solution is the correct one with good performance.  https://app.codility.com/demo/results/training4E8QZS-MQK/.

```
public class Solution5 {
    public int[] solution(int N, int[] A) {
        int[] counter = new int[N];
        int maxUpdate = 0, I, B = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            I = A[i] - 1;
            if (A[i] >= 1 && A[i] <= N) {
                counter[I] = Math.max(B,counter[I]) + 1;
                maxUpdate = Math.max(maxUpdate, counter[I]);
            } else if (A[i] == (N + 1)) {
                B = maxUpdate;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < counter.length; i++) {
            counter[i] = Math.max(B, counter[i]);
        }
        return counter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to postpone the max counters operation till the end. As you may have noticed, a counter's value is never used without first calculating the max with `B`, and `B` is what the max value (`maxUpdate`) was the last time an `N+1` was found in `A`. `maxUpdate` always contains the maximum value in the array of counters: it starts at zero like all the counters, and each time a counter is incremented, `maxUpdate` is updated.